# Is the expression (a=b) = k UB?

Tags: c++, expression, undefined-behavior

Is `(a = b ) = k` undefined behavior if a,b and k are of int type and properly initialised?

thanks

Comment: @Fox32: It does in C++, yes. Not in C.

Comment: My gut instinct tells me that this will be well-defined in C++0x.

Comment: @FredOverflow : Yes! The behavior is well defined in C++0x. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks UB to me. `a` is getting modified more than once b/w two sequence points.

The result of `(a=b)` is an lvalue<sup>1</sup> which is a reference to `a`

<sub>1  The result of the
assignment operation is the value stored in the left operand after the assignment has taken place; **the result
is an lvalue** ($5.17/1).</sub>

Comment: If the assignment operator is defined for their user defined class then there should be a sequence point in between, so the behavior should be defined.

Comment: @Andrei: `a`, `b` and `k` are of type `int` as mentioned in the question. So the behaviour is undefined.